# GraphQL relational data vs MongoDB document references

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, graphql

I'm new to GraphQL and am trying to learn the best way to use it with MongoDB.  GraphQL has a way to define the relationship between types as following:

```
type Booking {
        id: ID!
        date: String!
        author: [User!]!
        event: [Event!]!
    }
```

But, MongoDB also has a way to define the references between documents as following:

```
    event: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Event'
    },
    author: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
}
```

If I wanted to retrieve the authors of the Booking, I can either perform the search on the GraphQL's end in the resolver as following:

```
Booking: {
        author(parent, args, ctx, info) {
            return users.filter(user => {
                return user.id === parent.author;
            })
        }
    },
```

or I can use a MongoDB `find()` method on the result to find the authors from the `Booking.find()` in the resolver as following:

```
bookings: async () => {
    try {
      const bookings = await Booking.find();
      return bookings.map(booking => {
        return //perform MongoDB find() here to get the authors using the references
      });
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
}
```

My question is, is it necessary to define the relationship between data on the GraphQL's side as well as on the MongoDB side?  Which way of the two mentioned above is a better way to retrieve relational data?

Comment: If your idea is to tie both the back and the database in a way that respects the graph pattern I suggest using the database with new4j which is a database whose focus is to work with graphs, otherwise I do not see why you relate bank side Link new4j: https://neo4j.com/ Good Luck

Comment: What do you mean by bank side?